# Why don't grants from publicly-funded organizations systematically demand code and data to be released?

Tags: funding, data, open-access, code

I wonder why publicly-funded grants do not systematically demand from the recipients that code and data to be released, and results/papers to be publicly accessible. (put aside data that raise privacy issues)

Comment: Some do. 654321

Comment: This requirement has become much more common in the past few years; I suspect a combination of institutional inertia and uncertainty regarding the best long-term archival options has thus far arrested its progress.  At least NSF and NIH both require *some* form of data plan now.

Comment: In the UK, [this is now the case](http://www.rcuk.ac.uk/research/datapolicy/) as the default policy from the major public research funders. This is being driven by a number of things: public investment should lead to public knowledge, being able to validate results more easily, and better ability of business to innovate.

Comment: Related: [Why are CS researchers reluctant to share code and what techniques can I use to encourage sharing?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10247/why-are-cs-researchers-reluctant-to-share-code-and-what-techniques-can-i-use-to)

Answer (score 4):

Because there has not been a strong enough push to require it and some researchers prefer to keep code/data confidential. This is [currently a topic of discussion](https://www.eff.org/issues/open-access) at the national level led by organizations such as [EFF](https://www.eff.org/). This is hopefully a situation that will soon change for the better.